# Wrong classe names when Converting yolov5 to TFLite

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolov5, tflite

when i convert my trained yolov5 custom model best.pt to best-fp16.tflite with the commande :
!python yolov5/export.py  --weights best.pt  --include tflite .I got my converted weights with no issue
However, when I ran detection with my best-fp16.tflite : !python yolov5/detect.py --weights best-fp16.tflite  --source images.jpg . the detection works but the classe names are wrong.

Thanks.

wrong classe names

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

The model is still using the labels it was pretrained on (the benchmark labels) so to properly execute this command, make sure to include the argument --data data.yaml it should look like this:

```
!python yolov5/detect.py --weights best-fp16.tflite --data data.yaml --source images.jpg
```

The data.yaml file should contain the information about your dataset classes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).